# VideoView and MediaPlayer seekTo always starts from beginning

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have some problem with seeking video played in VideoView and resuming it.

Here's some part of my code:

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d("V", "onSeekComplete1 " + videoView.getCurrentPosition());
                videoView.start();
                Log.d("V", "onSeekComplete1 " + videoView.getCurrentPosition());
            }
        });
    }
});
videoView.setVideoURI('some local uri');
```

At some point I'm pausing video using:
`videoView.pause();`

After button click I'm seeking video to certain time, eg. 10 seconds (10 000 ms).

```
@OnClick(R2.id.ivMove)
void clickMove() {
   videoView.seekTo(10000);
}
```

After that in log I see:

```
onSeekComplete1 10000
onSeekComplete2 0
```

So after calling videoView.start() it is starting video from beginning!

But when I call start() without seeking video (eg. one button calls `pause()` and second calls `start()` then video is playing correctly - from the moment when it was paused, not from beginning.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by MediaPlayer - it is seeking to closest keyframe of the video and it turns out that my testing video has keyframes every ~30 seconds.

I changed to `ExoPlayer` https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer - it can seek to exact time.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new overload for the MediaPlayer seekTo method. It has a second int parameter, in which you can pass a SEEK_CLOSEST constant. According to Google, "This mode is used with seekTo(long, int) to move media position to a frame (not necessarily a key frame) associated with a data source that is located closest to or at the given time." In testing my own app, it solves the problem for API level >= 26. I'm not sure if there are any good options prior to API level 26.

Answer (score 0):

Try videoView.resume() instead of start()

```
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.d("V", "onSeekComplete1 " + videoView.getCurrentPosition());
                videoView.resume();
                Log.d("V", "onSeekComplete1 " + videoView.getCurrentPosition());
            }
        });
    }
});
videoView.setVideoURI('some local uri');
```

Comment: the same situation with resume() as with start()... :( 
When I call start() without seeking video (eg. one button calls ```pause()``` and second calls ```start()``` then video is playing correctly - from the moment when it was paused, not from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It works like charm....

```
   videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });

        }
    });
```